# Plugin to check mail loop

Tags: email, plugins, nagios

I'm trying to figure if there's already a plugin for Nagios which does the following:

- Sending an email from a mailbox A to a mailbox B, these mailboxes are on different mail servers.
- The mailbox B is configured on auto-answering received emails, so it sends an automatic answer to mailbox A
- Checking if mailbox A got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [`check_email_age`](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/IMAP4-and-POP3/check_email_age/details) plugin. It looks for the oldest email in the account, this can be quite easly amended to look for the newest email with a specific subject.